# Split Text File for Every x Lines

Tags: php, string, text

How do I split one text file into separate files based on the number of lines? For example the text file has 10000 lines, and I want to have 5 separate files with 2000 lines each.

I have tried this : [Split a text file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044262/split-a-text-file-in-php)

Basically I want a similar solution, but by counting the number of lines instead of bytes.

Thanks!

--edit--
I got it working following the hint from @user1477388

```
<?php

// get file contents into string
$stringData = file_get_contents('MyTextFile.txt');

// split by newline
$arrayData = split("\n", $stringData);

$fileCount = 0;

// loop through arrayData
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrayData); $i++)
{
    $file = 'myFileName';
    // for every 2000 lines, create a new file
    if ($i % 2000 == 0)
    {
        $fileCount++;
    }
    file_put_contents($file . $fileCount . '.txt', $arrayData[$i]."\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}

?>
```

Comment: Can't you use the `split` or `csplit` commands?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch He clearly states "I have tried this:"...

Comment: Are you defining a line as a series of characters separated by line-feed?  If so, maybe count every 2000th of those...

Comment: Yes, you will want to look at `split` like Basile said.  Check out http://md1.php.net/split and you will split your string (the text document) by `\r\n` which will give you an array that you can loop through.  Then, when looping, you can say that for every 2000 loops, create a new file.  It's quite simple.

Comment: Yeah this noob looked at `split` but was unsure the exact usage, especially for combining with loop. I got it working with the hint from below answers (will post revision soon). Thanks to all commenters/hinters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple like this:

```
$in = file("file");
$counter = 0; // to void warning    
while ($chunk = array_splice($in, 0, 2000)){
      $f = fopen("out".($counter++), "w");
      fputs($f, implode("", $chunk));
      fclose($f);
}
```

// not tested.

Comment: This created a copy of my text file, but with double line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how efficient this is or if it will even work, but at least it will give you a good starting point:

```
<?php

// get file contents into string
$stringData = file_get_contents('MyTextFile.txt');

// split by newline
$arrayData = split('\r\n', $stringData);

// loop through arrayData
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrayData); $i++)
{
    $file = 'myFileName';
    $fileCount = 1;
    // for every 2000 lines, create a new file
    if ($i % 2000 == 0)
    {
        $fileCount++;
    }
    file_put_contents($file . $fileCount . '.txt', $arrayData[$i], FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}

?>
```

- Code untested.

Comment: Not sure but I needed to change `'\r\n'` with `"\n"` for the split to work.  Also, moved `$fileCount = 1;` to outside/above of the loop so it won't return to 1 when the nested code is ran over again. But yes it's now solved. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, moving it outside the loop would make sense :)  Please accept and upvote answers that helped you.

Comment: Both answers worked fine, but I can't accept 2 answers. Will upvote when I have enough rep. Thank you!

Comment: Nope, you can only accept one - the one the helped you most.  You can upvote as many as you like.