# PHP: Insert line break after every $num word in a text file

Tags: php, text-files

I want to clean up a .txt file to make it more readable by inserting a line break after every 4th word. The file has been filled with data from an array.

This is what I've come up with so far by looking at [this](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?265789-How-to-add-a-linebreak-in-a-string-every-two-words) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238127/split-text-file-for-every-x-lines):

```
<?php
require "simple_html_dom.php";

$html = file_get_html("http://www.lipsum.com/");

$data = array();
$counter = 0;


foreach($html->find("div") as $tr){
    $row = array();
    foreach($tr->find("div") as $td){
        $row[] = $td->plaintext;
    }
     $data[] = $row;

    }


ob_start();
var_dump($data);

$data = preg_replace('~((\w+\s){4})~', '$1' . "\n", $data);
file_put_contents('new_text_file.txt', $data);


//$handlefile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
//file_put_contents('newfile.txt', $data);
//$output = ob_get_clean();
//$outputFile = "newfile.txt";


//fwrite($handlefile, $output);
//fclose($handlefile);



?>
```

As you can see I've created a for loop and two if statements to "count" the spacing between the words, and when the `counter` variable has reached 3, a line break is inserted. But it doesn't work since no data from the website is printed to the text file in the first place. It works however, if I remove the for loop and the if statements, without the sorting of course.
Any type of help is appriciated!

Edit: updated code.

Edit 2: final working version. Original question left for further reference.

This is the final working version:

```
<?php
require "simple_html_dom.php";

$html = file_get_html("http://www.lipsum.com/");
$data = array();
$counter = 0;


foreach($html->find("div") as $tr){
    $row = array();
    foreach($tr->find("div") as $td){
        $row[] = $td->plaintext;
    }
     $data[] = $row;

    }


ob_start();
var_dump($data);
$handlefile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
file_put_contents('newfile.txt', $data);
$output = ob_get_clean();
$outputFile = "newfile.txt";
fwrite($handlefile, $output);
fclose($handlefile);

function MakeFileReadable($source , $export) {

    $content = file_get_contents($source);
    $x = explode (" " , $content);

    $newx = "";
    $count = 1;
    foreach ($x as $word) {
        $newx .= $word . " ";
        if ($count %12 ==0) $newx .= "\r\n";
        $count ++;
    }

    $fp = fopen("file-export.txt" , 'w');
    if (!$fp) die("There is a problem with opening file...");
    fwrite($fp , $newx);
    fclose($fp);

}

MakeFileReadable("newfile.txt" , "file-export.txt");

?>
```

Comment: Where you set value to $string ? what does it contain?

Answer (score 5):

Use some array functions

```
$string = "one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven tweleve thirteen fourteen";

$arr = explode (" " , $string);
$lines = array_chunk($arr,4);
foreach($lines as $line) 
   echo implode (" ", $line)."\r\n";
```

result

```
one two three four
five six seven eight
nine ten eleven tweleve
thirteen fourteen
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I can't get it to work. Just to clarify, where in my code should I put your example?

Comment: This is the easier to read answer, although the regex of chris85 is pretty elegant. @bork if you post your current code to a phpfiddle.org I will check your code for you

Comment: The "\r\n" as you probably figured it out by now @bork, needs to be replaced with "<br />", just thought I'd say it here for the record.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a regex solution.

```
<?php
$test = 'one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven tweleve thirteen fourteen';
echo preg_replace('~((\w+\s){4})~', '$1' . "\n", $test);
```

Output:

```
one two three four 
five six seven eight 
nine ten eleven tweleve
```

`\w` is a word character (Alphanumeric characters plus "_", http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), if you only want `A-Z` use `[a-z]` and use the `i` modifier to make it case insensitive, `~((\w+\s){4})~i`. The `\s` is a whitespace and the `{4}` is requiring 4 occurrences of the `\w+\s`.

Per your code...

```
$data = preg_replace('~((\w+\s){4})~', '$1' . "\n", $data);
file_put_contents('new_text_file.txt', $data);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Per updated code:

```
<?php
require "simple_html_dom.php";
$html = file_get_html("http://www.lipsum.com/");
$data = array();
$counter = 0;
foreach($html->find("div") as $tr){
    $row = array();
    foreach($tr->find("div") as $td){
        $row[] = $td->plaintext;
    }
    $data[] = $row;
}
$data = preg_replace('~((\w+\s){4})~', '$1' . "\n", implode(' ', $data));
file_put_contents('new_text_file.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I don't really understand how I should apply it to the content of a text file.

Comment: Where is `$string` set, what is it, the text content? What are you trying to do with the `newfile.txt`, put the string in there with the content broken by every fourth word?

Comment: I want the content from `var_dump($data);`, which is printed to the text file, to be broken by every fourth word.

Comment: Sorry, missed you replies. Tried your suggestions and it doesn't do anything. But I might be placing the code snippet in the wrong position? I put it beneath my `var_dump($data);`

Comment: That was just so `$data` would have the right data. You still need to output however you are saving it to. I'll make a sample with `file_put_contents` which will demonstrate how to put this into a new text file.

Comment: The `var_dump` shows data in `$data`? Could you update your question so it has where `$string` is set.

Comment: Updated, brings up a few questions though. What is your plan with entities? Are you just trying to split this so it is smaller for multiple files or is it suppose to make sense?

Comment: It's supposed to be searchable. And the result should be corresponding to the original data. Hence why I can't have the original data jumbled up, or sorted in any other way in the text file. For example, I search for the word Ipsum in the text file, the word should appear in the same places in the text file as on the website. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you for your support, I've solved my problem now. Check my updated question for the result.

Answer (score 1):

Finally tested code:

```
    <?php
function MakeFileReadable($source , $export) {

    $content = file_get_contents($source);
    $x = explode (" " , $content);

    sort($x);
    $newx = "";
    $count = 1;
    foreach ($x as $word) {
        $newx .= $word . " ";
        if ($count %4 ==0) $newx .= "\r\n";
        $count ++;
    }

    $fp = fopen($export , 'w');
    if (!$fp) die("There is a problem with opening file...");
    fwrite($fp , $newx);
    fclose($fp);

}

MakeFileReadable("file-input.txt" , "file-export.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I can't get it to function, it doesn't give me any errors, but it doesn't sort the data in the file either. (I removed my for and ifs)

Comment: You need to sort words?

Comment: I've edited for sort. see more sort functionality in 
  http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I meant, **it doesn't perform the line breaks in the file either**. I don't really need to sort the data, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Not really unfortunately. I'm getting an error on `$x = explode (" " , $content);` now. `Undefined variable`. I think it's $x that's causing it.

Comment: I have tested finally in my own webserver, just consider file.txt and newfile.txt, should be replaced.

Comment: Did you got the result?

Comment: I get all of the data sorted from smallest number to last letter. But no line breaks or data in the file-export.txt

Comment: Now I've removed echo, but tried other method of saving, should be responsed or error if file is less accessible

Comment: Tried the new code. I get some blank characters in file-export now when I run it. Nothing else though, no errors or other messages.

Comment: I tinkered a bit myself, and now the data is written to file-export. But it's sorted by numbers and words. I'd rather keep the lines as they are, the words and numbers in their original order.

Comment: Thank you for your support, I've solved my problem now. Check my updated question for the result.