# Split one file and make them into two

Tags: php

```
//expression to be found in file name
$find = '.5010.';

//directory name
//we will store renamed files here
$dirname = '5010';
if(!is_dir($dirname))
    mkdir($dirname, 0777);

//read all files from a directory
//skip directories
$directory_with_files = './';
$dh  = opendir($directory_with_files);
$files = array();
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh)))
{
    if(in_array($filename, array('.', '..')) || is_dir($filename))
        continue;

    $files[] = $filename;
}

//iterate collected files
foreach($files as $file)
{
    //check if file name is matching $find
    if(stripos($file, $find) !== false)
    {

        //open file
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        if ($handle)
        {
            //read file, line by line
            while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false)
            {

                //find REF line
                $refid = 'REF*2U*'; 
                if(stripos($line, $refid) !== false) 
                    { 
                    //glue refernce numbers 
                    //check if reference number is not empty 

                    $refnumber = str_replace(array($refid, '~'), array('', ''), $line);
                if($refnumber != '') 
                    { 
                $refnumber = '_'. $refnumber .'_'; 

                $filerenamed = str_replace($find, $refnumber, $file); 
                    copy($file, $dirname . '/' . $filerenamed); 
                        } 

                echo $refnumber . "\n"; 
                    }
            }

            //close file
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
}
```

I have the code above, to read my files that contain ".5010." and replace it with the characters after REF*2U*. However in some files there are more than one REF*2U*, is there a code that would split them through a line called "N1*PR*" and output 2 files each with its own REF*2U* character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[stream_get_line](http://php.net/stream_get_line) would do the trick
string stream_get_line ( resource $handle , int $length [, string $ending ] )

Quoting the documentation,

> Reading ends when length bytes have been read, when the string
>   specified by ending is found (which is not included in the return
>   value), or on EOF (whichever comes first).

So looping through the lines of file checking fro the specific string as follows is an example:

```
$i = 1;
while(! feof($file)) {
    $contents = stream_get_line($file,1000,"REF*2U*");
    file_put_contents('new_file_'.$i.'.txt',$contents);
    $i++;
}
```

[Similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2044424/3124552)

Comment: What variables does it need?